# Robotstxt shows service unavailable

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, robots.txt

I have the robotstxt module active on my site, but for some reason when I visit the URL: example.site/robots.txt the browser displays a text saying "Service unavailable"

Interestingly, the same message is also shown even if I disable the module.

How can I remove this example.site/robots.txt completely?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually caused by a problem in writting file permissions.

Try to echo phpinfo(), and check if allow_url_fopen is enabled.

About the 'service unavaliable' remaining after uninstall, can be caused by cache (did you clean the drupal's cache after disabling this module?).

Other possible solution would be inspect the redirect module rules or htaccess file to check a possible redirect.

Comment: @denielarend yes I cleared the cache several times and also, in the redirect module, I set a redirect from the example.site/robots.txt to the home page, which does not work either.

Comment: @useragent, if drupal can't redirect it, then the file robots.txt may exist, but corrupted. Drupal can't handle non-drupal routes. I would focus more deeply in this file  or .htaccess

Comment: @danielrend aside from the robotstxt module I indeed found a robotstxt in a base theme. What would be the best approach?
I thought of deleting the file, but the problem is that other sites make usage of the same theme.